# Regex to allow string certain at beginning of input

Tags: jquery, html, regex, validation

I'm using [jqBootstrapValidation](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation) with the following regex embedding in an HTML form to semi-validate FQDNs for a basic CSR generator.

`regex="(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]).)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])"`

I'd like to be able to allow the `*.` characters at the beginning in order to allow wildcard domains to be entered.

e.g. allow `*.example.com` as well as `example.com` and `sub.example.com`

I've tried adding `([*.]?)` at the front for the following:

`regex="(([*.]?)([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]).)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])"`

I'm new to regular expressions. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: So, fully-qualified domain name I can guess; what's CSR?

Comment: [Certificate Signing Request](https://www.google.com/search?q=csr+generator).

Comment: can you post a few examples of valid strings? what you have now and what you want

Comment: @arieljuod He wants any FQDN, or a FQDN starting with `*.` to match any subdomain, e.g. "google.com" or "*.google.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the expression you should be using, per individual FQDN:

```
^(([*][.])?([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

There were a couple of issues with your expression:

1. If you want to match a series of characters exactly, put each one inside its own `[]` brackets, one after the other. So you wanted `[*][.]`, which matches `*.`, not `[*.]` (which matches *either* `*` *or* `.`, but not both).
2. I made the `*.` at the start optional using `?`.
3. You should surround the entire thing with `^` and `$` so that it matches the entire string, not just a domain inside the string (e.g. "Not part of the domain.com matching" would match because of "domain.com").
4. The dot in the middle matching subdomain separators was not escaped, which tells Regex to allow any character there, so `sub#domain.com` was valid. I escaped it with `\.` so that it only matches the `.` character.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating what will and won't match with this expression:

http://www.rexfiddle.net/s7iXFLR

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. Thanks for pointing out my other issues, much appreciated. Thanks also for the rexfiddle link too! Am sure it'll help ease my learning curve.

Comment: Any ideas how I would avoid multi level wildcard subdomains being valid? e.g. `*.sub.sub.example.com`?

Comment: `"Not part of the domain.com matching" would match` I don't see a literal `*.` in that string.

Comment: The `*.` is optional.

Comment: Don't see anything in the regex matching whitespace.

Comment: If you don't anchor the input string with `^` and `$`, it will match any part of the string (anything inside of it, too), not the entire string as a whole. So, the expression `apple` will match the string "This apple is delicious.", but not if you use the expression `^apple$`, then it would only match if the string were "apple", exactly.

Comment: I got ya. Yes, apparently the anchors are needed.

Answer (score 2):

SpikeX is the general answer, this is one for a single dot domain.
**Edit2:** *.Single  or  Multi level

```
 #  ^(\*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|(([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$

 ^ 
 (
      \*\. 
      ( [a-zA-Z0-9]+ - )*
      [a-zA-Z0-9]+ 
      \.
   |  
      (
           ( [a-zA-Z0-9]+ - )*
           [a-zA-Z0-9]+ 
           \.
      )+
 )
 [A-Za-z] 
 ( [A-Za-z0-9-]* [A-Za-z0-9] )?
 $
```

**Edit3:**  *Edit2* + localhost

```
 #  ^(localhost|(\*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|(([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)$

 ^ 
 (
      localhost
   |  
      (
           \*\. 
           ( [a-zA-Z0-9]+ - )*
           [a-zA-Z0-9]+ 
           \.
        |  
           (
                ( [a-zA-Z0-9]+ - )*
                [a-zA-Z0-9]+ 
                \.
           )+
      )
      [A-Za-z] 
      ( [A-Za-z0-9-]* [A-Za-z0-9] )?
 )
 $
```

**Or**, to do it justice *edit3* in Perl/PCRE, but don't think Jquery can do that (don't know).

```
 #  ^(?:localhost|(?:(\*\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)|(?1)+)[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)$

 ^ 
 (?:
      localhost
   |  
      (?:
           (
                \*\. 
                (?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+ - )*
                [a-zA-Z0-9]+ 
                \.
           )
        |  
           (?1)+ 
      )
      [A-Za-z] 
      (?: [A-Za-z0-9-]* [A-Za-z0-9] )?
 )
 $
```

Comment: Have just tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Won't validate any type of domain wildcard or not. Would this be due to the formatting?

Comment: Give me an example of what it won't match (validate).

Comment: I've copied an paste your expression into my form: `regex="^(\*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$"`, `*.example.com`, `example.com`, and `sub.example.com` all don't validate.

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Try new one.

Comment: The last one is further reduced.

Comment: Yep. It works now, but not for sub domains or domains without a tld, e.g. `sub.domain.com` or `localhost`. [http://www.rexfiddle.net/pRSQHqu](http://www.rexfiddle.net/pRSQHqu) . But you did say it's for a single domain. Many thanks

Comment: Is it possible (using regex) to allow only a single level domain if it begins with `*.` but allow multi-level domains if it doesn't begin with `*.`?

Comment: Thanks for all those edits. Much appreciated. Has helped me understand the way regex's work a lot better.